# /usr/bin/env: node --harmony: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, n

I have searched online thru this site and others for a solution, so I finally bow my head and ask for help.  It looks like most of the answers are identifying the node/nodejs naming conflict and creating symlinks as a solution.  I don't have a nodejs anywhere on my system.

I am using a **_  n _** as my node version manager.  So,

```
sudo n
```

displays a list of installed versions and allows me to choose. n simply copies the chosen version into /usr/local/bin/ as node.  It has already established a link from /usr/bin/node to the managed version.

I installed a javascript library called 'waigo.'  When I run the following:

```
waigo init
```

I get the following output...

```
/usr/bin/env: node --harmony: No such file or directory
```

arrgghhh.....  I'm frustrated.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Potentially you just don't have /usr/bin/node in your PATH, so 'node' on its own isn't resolving to the executable you want it to. What does 'echo $PATH' output?

Comment: echo $PATH provides a list of all the directories in the path.  And when I run which node, I get "/usr/local/bin/node"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line in a shell script which specifies the program used to interpret the file. This might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony
```

The error message in your case suggests that `env` is attempting to locate "node --harmony" which was probably a problem with the executable file run when you typed `waigo`. For example, it might have had a shebang line incorrectly formatted like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env "node --harmony"
```